# Hibernate doesn´t work as expected

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, session

I am trying to update MySQL table with hibernate. It looks like that it does work, result from hibernate is 1, but table doesn´t change. My code for update :

```
Session session = GeneralSession.getSession();
session.beginTransaction();

//some code - initialization and logics
//loop
Query updateDuplicity = session .createSQLQuery("UPDATE `t_inzerat` set `actual` = 'D' 
WHERE `id` = "+ idSimi);
int resultUpdate = updateDuplicity.executeUpdate();

session.flush();
//end of loop

session.getTransaction().commit();
```

In console hibernate writes this as:

```
Hibernate: UPDATE `t_inzerat` set `actual` = 'D' WHERE `id` = 5611
Affected rows : 1
```

Please what is wrong? Thank you

Comment: any specific reason for using statements instead of prepared statements?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here[example](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-transaction-handle-example/). Do the commit in the tx returned by beginTransaction method

Comment: this statement is ok??? 
Query updateDuplicity = session    .createSQLQuery("UPDATE `t_inzerat` set `actual` = 'D' WHERE `id` = "
+ idSimi);

Comment: You can try to run it directly in the sql console. If works there is ok. I would not use "`"